# Sharepoint 2010 Certification 70-573 retired?

Tags: certification

Is Microsoft SharePoint certification #70-573 retired?

I am interested in taking up this exam as I have 1 year experience in SharePoint 2010.

If this certification is retired, please suggest other SharePoint exams that goes well with 1 year of experience.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [retired exams](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/retired-certification-exams.aspx) list, none of SharePoint 2010 exams towards MCITP or MCPD have expired.

MCITP is scheduled to expire in January 2016.

I don't have any particular suggestions as it is very straight-forward: either MCPD or MCITP or both. You can also move your focus towards SP2013 and Office 365, but keep in mind that these new certifications appear to expire after 2 years or so.

> Recertify
>
> This MCSD certification requires you to show continued
> ability to perform in your chosen solution area by completing a
> recertification exam every two years.

More [here](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/sharepoint-certification.aspx).